# HTTP Status - 401 Unauthorized

Tags: spring, rest, api, oauth-2.0

I'm trying to convert from curl to java code with intention to call an API to create a token but I get a 401 response.

Curl code:

```
curl -X POST \
  https://apigw.dev/commercial/oauth/create-token \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
  -d 'client_id=dfdfdfdfd&client_secret=dfdfdf&grant_type=client_credentials'
```

And here my java code:

```
@RestController
public class TokenController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/getAccessToken", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ClientCredentialsResourceDetails getAccessToken(ClientCredentialsResourceDetails resource) throws Exception {

        resource.setAccessTokenUri(tokenUri);
        resource.setClientId(clientId);
        resource.setClientSecret(clientSecret);
        resource.setGrantType("client_credentials");
        resource.setClientAuthenticationScheme(AuthenticationScheme.header);
        resource.setScope(Arrays.asList("read", "write"));

        System.out.println(resource);

        return resource;
    }
}
```

and here the results:

```
    "timestamp": "2020-04-28T14:02:28.381+0000",
    "status": 401,
    "error": "Unauthorized",
    "message": "Unauthorized",
    "path": "/getAccessToken"
}
```

I really appreciate your suggestion, Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to do - are you writing a client for a public API or creating one yourself (if not, then what is the purpose of the `create-token` endpoint).

You should also remove your client ID and secret.

Comment: i have fix my question, it's clear i think. can you suggest me.

Comment: it looks to me like you have spring security active, and spring security is protecting the getAccessToken endpoint. You either need to setup security, or instruct spring security to allow all access for /getAccessToken.

Comment: i have configure spring security, but the response become 403.

{
    "timestamp": "2020-04-29T02:45:26.770+0000",
    "status": 403,
    "error": "Forbidden",
    "message": "Forbidden",
    "path": "/getAccessToken"
}

Comment: So turn on spring security debug logging to see what it is complaining about.

Answer (score 0):

You're making a POST request with CURL, but your rest controller is configured as GET. I guess you have another endpoint to /getAccessToken with POST method wich requires the token.
Also, by default, every mehod in a `@RestController` class will consume an `application/json` and produce an `application/json`.
If your request is a `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, change the consume type of your request to `MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE`.

Comment: before it i have try using POST method but i still get status 401.